# deserializing objects in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, ostringstream

I know how to serialize an object in the following way:

```
void encodeMsg(char **msg, const ConnectionParams& params)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    if (!(oss << params))
    {
        //failure
    }
    msg = oss.str();
}
```

how can i deserialize a message back into the object?

meaning i want to have this method:

```
ConnectionParams encodeMsg(char *msg)
    { ... }
```

so i don't have an instringstream object... how can i do that?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question.  But that code won't do anything useful unless you use "char** msg".

Comment: If you can do `outstream << obj` for some obj, you should be able to do `instream >> obj`.

Comment: @Nick yeah forgot that thank you :)

Comment: @Ivella: and who allocats the memory ?

Comment: @lvella all i got is const char *buff meaning the string of the object. i don't have an instream object

Comment: @MatthieuM. `obj` should already be an allocated object, if the class has internal objects on heap, that should be taken care by `operator>>` and `operator<<`.

Comment: @YonatanNir You could do `std::istringstream iss(buff);` to get `iss` as an input stream.

Comment: Your code has a dangling pointer in msg since the stream is released at the end of the function.

Comment: In the context of iostreams, the shift operators `<<` and `>>` usually mean "formatted I/O", and not "serialization".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
ConnectionParams decodeMsg(char *msg)
{
  ConnectionParams ret;
  std::istringstream iss(msg);
  iss >> ret;
  return ret;
}
```

That is assuming that this class was made to be serializable with `operator<<`, and provides the symmetrically opposite operation `operator>>`. There is no way to serialize an arbitrary C++ object without knowing its internals, and in this answer I am assuming these operation were already implemented by the class provider.

Also, note that you should probably pass ConnectionParams as reference, like:

```
void encodeMsg(char *msg, ConnectionParams& ret);
```

Also, your encodeMsg is wrong, has better chance to work as:

```
void encodeMsg(char **msg, const ConnectionParams& params)
{
    ....
    *msg = oss.str();
}
```

and even this is wrong, since oss.str() returns an internal pointer from oss, and you can't return it to the caller, because oss will be destroyed upon function return, and the pointer will be invalid. You'd better return a std::string or something like that.

EDIT:
What if the class does not provides the means to serialize and deserialize itself? On classes that are simple enough, and don't hold pointers allocated on heap, nor file descriptors, nor have fancy behaviors on constructors and destructors, you may be able to do it the same way done with old C structs: interpret all its bytes as a buffer. Note that this is dangerous, type unsafe, and the buffer may not be inter-operable between different compilers/architectures.

```
// DISCLAIMER: Untested code!

class A {
  int plain_variable;
  char palin_array[50];
};
// Class A is ok to serialize this way

class B {
  A plain_object_array[10];
  double another_plain_variable;
};
// Class B is ok to serialize this way

class C {
  float plain_object;
  std::string fancy_string;
};
// Class C is *NOT* ok to serialize this way, because it contains an string,
// which, in turn, contains a heap allocated pointer

template<class T>
void serialize(const T& obj, std::string& buff)
{
  const char *accessor = (const char *)&obj;
  std::string tmp(accessor, sizeof(obj));
  std::swap(buff, tmp);
}

template<class T>
void deserialize(const std::string& buff, T& obj)
{
  char *accessor = (char *)&obj;
  std::copy(buff.begin(), buff.end(), accessor);
}
```

See, the conditions for this scheme to work are so that it is unlikely you will be able to use it with a third-party provided class. In the end, you will probably need to store all the data needed to rebuild the object yourself, and work on this data.

Comment: For a deserialization function, maybe the best name is `decodeMsg`... (just my 2 cents)

Comment: @lvella they were actually don't.. i hoped to have something which does it easily like you can with Json which i know at least from java.. isn't there a way to do something like that in C++? if not then i have to overload the >> and << operators manually?

Comment: @YonatanNir There is a way to do if you have some guarantees on the class internals, I'll edit my answer.